# Asp.net core 2.0 RequireHttpsMetadata=false for Development

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

> InvalidOperationException: The MetadataAddress or Authority must use
>   HTTPS unless disabled for development by setting
>   RequireHttpsMetadata=false.

Where do I set this?

I've tried in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`

```
if (_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    services.AddMvc(opts => opts.RequireHttpsPermanent = false);
```

Still receive the error.
Also tried to put it in Web.Config just to let me debug locally.

```xml
<RequireHttpsMetadata>false</RequireHttpsMetadata>
```

Neither work. I can't find any documentation from MS on where to set this!

I'm using jwt bearer authentication.

Comment: You'll want to set `JwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerOptions.cs#L23)). If you need more information/an example, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, thankyou! that fixed it!

Comment: How can I solve this by using HTTPS instead? What URL in particular must be using a secure connection?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add JwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata to false as ConfigureServices as @kirk Larkin has suggested above.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Authority"];
                options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Comment: The solution does not suggest setting it to false on Development environment only as requested by OP. Currently it can cause unintended enabling of HTTP in Production too which at worst may create vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 6):

`options.Authority` needs to be a secured connection. Omitting the protocol will default to http, so be sure to explicitly set this url to https. `RequireHttpsMetadata=false` should only be used in development scenarios--so you should be checking the hosting env before setting this to false.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd add some code to show how to define a check whether the host environment is in "Development" or not. Which makes your code less prone to vulnerabilities since you won't have to change it before going into production. Hope this helps others searching for this issue as well.

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public IHostingEnvironment HostEnvironment { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    HostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
           {
               opt.Audience = Configuration["AAD:ResourceId"]; 
               opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AAD: Instance"]}{Configuration["AAD:TenantId"]}";
               if (HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
               {   // to make sure this is only used during development
                   opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
               }
           });
}

// rest omitted
```